# How to access a interbase/firebird db via network with two or more computers

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, interbase

I made a program that accesses a firebird DB in network environment.

I access the DB via Network in two different points of the network normally.

But if I open the two programs simultaneously this exception is thrown on the second program, which tries to connect to DB:

"Your user name and password are not definied"

How to access the firebird DB with two connections simultaneously?

Comment: "Your user name and password are not defined" doesn't suggest there's a limitation on simultaneous connections. It suggests that one client is using incorrect firebird login credentials. Are you sure both programs using the same login credentials and connection details?

Comment: Did you try creating a second account and using a different login?  While I'm pretty sure Interbase allows multiple sign-ons with the same account by default, you could easily create a second account just to verify that this is what is happening.

Comment: What components are you using to connect to the database? You need to connect using TCP, but obviously the details depend on the actual component set. For example Sam's answer, while correct, is not useful if you're using Interbase Express, because IBX has a `TIbDatabase` components that has a `DatabaseName` property (ie: you no "connection" component). Steve's method is probably also correct, but again, IBX doesn't have a `server` property, you specify that in the database name. Also your error message suggests you suppressed the login dialog without manually providing user name and password.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by using the embedded versionof firebird, which only allows 1 connection. Look at the filename you installed.

If that is the problem then uninstall that and install the clasic or superserver version instead

Comment: Notice the answer above is not uptodate, with version 2.5 of firebird according to http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg25-classic-or-super.html "Windows Embedded now contains a SuperClassic instead of a SuperServer engine. File locks are shared, so a database can be accessed by one or more Embedded servers and a regular Classic or SuperClassic server at the same time."

Answer (score 0):

MAke sure that the Firebird database is hosted on a computer that is running the Firebird server.

ie Install Firebird Server on the computer that has the database.

Then from your client PCs where your app is installed make sure that you are accessing the database by connecting to the Firebird server. This means that whichever component your Delphi app is using to connect to the database needs to have the 'server' property set to the hostname of the database server machine.

Once this is done your apps will be making requests to the Firebird database server which knows how to handle the connections and process the SQL requests and return results.

Answer (score 0):

Most db connection components should allow you to precede the database path with an ip address or hostname like this for example

```
MyConnection.Database := '127.0.0.1:C:\Databases\testdb.fdb';
```

Obviously make sure both your programs point to the same ip address or hostname and make sure the login credentials they use are defined on that firebird server.

All firebird server installations (except embedded) can handle multiple connections by default (even using the same user), you shouldn't have to worry about that. Just make sure the client programs are using inputs (ie. db network path and firebird server login credentials) that apply on the server they are trying to connect to. You could just use SYSDBA until you get the connection under control, then start thinking about creating a unique login for your client apps to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the `TIBDatabase` component, you have to fill the `Params` property with:

```
user_name=sysdba 
password=masterkey
```

The Firebird installation in every computer in the LAN has to be set to this default parameters. The computer with problem must have a different access credential.

You have to uninstall Firebird and them reinstall the latest version using the service and super server options, and mark the "use gdi32.dll for retro..."

Tell me if that worked out for you.